# Redirect http://- to https:// with tsung recorder

Tags: erlang, tsung, tsung-recorder

I’m trying to run tsung-recorder from my ubuntu VM

I have set up a proxy in firefox, localhost:8090

The site I'm trying to use tsung-recorder with is https://

According to [the docs](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/proxy.html)

> For HTTPS recording, use `http://-` instead of `https://` in your browser

My app is also a single page app, which makes requests to apis from the client.
With this approach, my app is trying to make requests to `http://-api.whatever.com` when it should be `https://api.whatever.com`

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hook your browser into the the proxy recorder and start it up, it should automatically add the handle the conversion where necessary while you hit the api. I'm not sure why your API would fail. Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want use url as `http://api.whatever.com` instead `http://-api.whatever.com` . I don't know why, but if it is really need you can use something like Haproxy to redirect from `http://api.whatever.com` to `http://-api.whatever.com`